# Android Device isn't showing in Android studio

Tags: android, adb

I've just started developing android apps. I want to run my first app on my android device. According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) topic I've being doing it for an hour but i couldn't find my device while I've turned on the debugger option on my device. There is no running device in the *choose a running device* option. What obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Are you trying to use a real device? Have you installed its drivers?

Comment: Yes, it's a real device. The drivers were installed automatically as I connected my phone to PC.

Comment: have you checked in command line the result of `adb devices` ? Check if your device shows up.

Comment: I would still recommend to try installing the official driver from a producer's website.

Comment: While not out of the question, I'd be suspicious of the idea that **ADB** drivers were installed automatically.  More likely, if something was installed, it was for an end-user capability unrelated to the ADB functionality you require as a developer.  (Of course if you are not on Windows, there is not step of "installing" drivers involved at all)

Answer (score 1):

Go to developer options , there will be an option : Select Revoke USB debugging authorisation. Click OK.

Also go to storage options and USB connection type as camera ptp.
Disconnect from cable.

Restart your phone.
Enable debug option.
Connect cable.

You will see a dialog asking for authorisation. Check allow always option and click OK.

Now it will be connected.

Comment: Please tell me the full address to *Revoke USB authorization*. I can't find developer option in the Android Studio.

Comment: U need to find this option in settings of your android device.

Comment: I did as you said but it's still not working, it's just exactly the same case as mentioned above.

Comment: Did u got authorisation dialog asking for permission ?

Comment: Try changing USB computer connection to Media device (MTP)

Comment: Did that too. that doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Which device you are using ? Also tell me which OS u using on PC.

Comment: Android device is *Samsung galaxy duos*.

OS is *Windows*

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging in developer options. Also make sure your developer options are ON.

Comment: I did that in the very start. The Android Studio seems like it will never show me my device. It has not even taken a step towards solution.